# IP Tables forwarding issue

Tags: iptables, linux-networking

Thank you in advance for the assistance.

I have tried reading on here and searching but I can't seem to get it to work.

Computer A: 192.168.1.2
Computer B: 192.168.1.3

I am trying to send a UDP message from .2 to .3 and changing the port. .2 will send a message on 1003 and i want .3 to accept it on 1004.

The code below is placed on the .3 computer

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -i eth0 -d 192.168.1.2 --dport 1003 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.3:1004
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d 192.168.1.2 -p udp --dport 1003 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1004
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -p udp -d 192.168.1.2 --dport 1004 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Don't mask private IPs. This don't enhance any security, but makes it harder to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your matches are wrong. They'll fire if the *destination* was `192.168.1.2`. In your case, the *source* is `192.168.1.2` and the destination is `192.168.1.3`.

Also, it seems you only need only `DNAT` rule **or** a `REDIRECT` rule, not both.

The filtering rule should be in the `INPUT` chain, because destination is the local machine. I see no point in using `state` module in this rule, but there may be a need to add other connection tracking related rules; it is unclear if those are needed at all. This depends on the rest of the firewall. If there is nothing in the firewall, no filter rules are necessary, because everything will be enabled anyway.

By the way, `state` is obsolete, you should use `conntrack` module, `ctstate` match instead.

So, you seem to need the following two rules:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.1.2 -d 192.169.1.3 -p udp --dport 1003 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1004
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.2 -p udp --dport 1004 -j ACCEPT
```

First rule redirects incoming packet to 1003 to the port 1004 (and back for outgoing packets). The second rule actually permits this translated packet to reach a local process.